# version number of a commit hash in github

Tags: git, github, github-release

I am new to GitHub. I am currently researching an issue of an open software available in GitHub, so I want to know the version number of the open software software for which the commit (solution to correct the issue) hash number for the solution.

To make it clear I have done the following:

1. I have searched the issue from the NVD website and got the link of github issue discussion from there.
2. I came across the patch with their commits in github  .
3. I have used git log command in gitbash to extract the details of the commit.

I want to know the version of the open software where the issue has been resolved by the commit number.

How can I do that?

I am using Git Bash as my command line.

Comment: Can you share link to that software, does it follow github releases?
For example: https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/releases showing releases for `edx-platform`.

Comment: Ya sure this is the link https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/872 and I am not sure about the github releases but yeah it has 110 releases . So the release link is https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/releases

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the maintainers of a Github repository reference their commits OR pull requests to the Github Issues if solving those issues need modifications in the codebase.

In your case, there were commits where the [issue#872](http://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/872) was referenced:

[image]

Now you just need to see the [releases page](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/releases) to see which release tag contains the relevant commit.

```
# It can also be achieved via git commandline as follow
$ git describe --tags <commit-hash> # e.g. fb89192
```

It is: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/releases/tag/7.0.7-12

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have figured that out but my question is can i find about this version of ImageMagick from the commit number e.g 'ce3a586' in gitbash command prompt by writing a specific command or this is the only way?  Thanks again

Comment: @AnkhiRoy yes that can also be achieved via console if we know the commit hash. Let me update the answer with it.

Comment: @AnkhiRoy please don't forget accept/upvote if this answers your question – Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the commit page ( https://github.com/handruin/spdif-ka/commit/01938a6 for example ) there is a list of tags which include the patch. It is just under the commit message. It is not there for mobile version though, only at desktop.

Here is how my link looks (sorry for the qualuty, I'm using mobile here):
[image: screenshot]

The earliest tag there is v1.0.3.1

Looks like for your commits, there is no release yet

Comment: This is great ... if it's there. Unfortunately many commits on GitHub don't have this information even though they have been included in a release. Example: https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/commit/71d343e02dc49f3981cff5383b1ff76ff34eedc0